# How to call a specific user default in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, settings.bundle, application-settings

I'm trying to call up a specific setting that is saved in the settings bundle of my iphone app.  I want to do an if statement based on what was saved. My code in the implementation file looks like this:

```
branchMatch = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[defaults objectForKey:@"branch"]];
```

The object in the settings file is just the name of the specific branch. I keep getting the SIGABRT error but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hair pulling, I realized that I need to load user defaults from the delegate class instead of the ViewController.

Thanks for all the input

Answer (score 6):

First, there's no need to initialize a string with another string. Assuming that branchMatch is a `NSString*`, the following would suffice:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
branchMatch = (NSString*)[defaults objectForKey:@"branch"];
```

Second, check if `objectForKey` returns a `nil`. Your SIGABRT is, most likely, due to a nil there.

EDIT: those values aren't present in the collection until the user opens up Settings and explicitly changes them. It's up to you to provide the sensible value if the setting is not found (is `nil`). The ones in the settings bundle are not automatically applied; they are only for the Settings app to initialize its UI properly.

Comment: Thanks...I've recoded it to:
NSString *branchName = [defaults objectForKey:@"branch"];

and my result is returning a "null" (I used alertview to display the result).  Now I don't know why I'm getting null.

Comment: I've checked my Identifier in the settings root.plist and it is definitely "branch".  My default value is "Edmonton". The full code for this section is:

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *branchName = [defaults objectForKey:@"branch"];

  
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Branch"
                                                        message:branchName
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

Comment: My app is a tab bar app.  On the first tab, I have a Picker that displays 7 branches to choose from.  In the settings default, I've set it to show "Edmonton".  I'm calling the NSUserDefaults in a separate tab...is that the problem?

Comment: By "settings default", do you mean the one in the settings bundle? That one is not applied until the user runs Settings. If you're writing into NSUserDefaults yourself, do you call `synchronize`?

Comment: I'm calling synchronize when I save the file but not when I'm trying to load the NSUserDefaults...should I be?...and if so, where?

Comment: Not sure. If you're calling `[NSUserDefauls standardUserDefaults]`, that should synchronize internally IIRC. If you store the NSDefaults object for a while, yes you should sync before reading.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  At least I'm passed the SIGABRT error.  I've tested my default in the View that allows you to set it and it works...I must be losing the data between views

Comment: Is it because I am using a Tab Bar?  I have a UIPicker in my firstView and when I set up an alert view to display the value of @"branch", it shows what I have there, but when I use the same code in my thirdView, I get "null".  How am I losing the data?

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking that the objectForKey call isn't returning nil?

Comment: Yes it is...not sure why yet.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead :

```
NSUserDefault* defaults = [NSUserDefauls standardUserDefaults];
NSString* setting = [defaults objectForKey:@"branch"];
if (setting)
    // Do what needed if branch is set
else
    // Do what needed if branch has never been set
```